# Multipage "dcases" environment

Tags: page-breaking, cases

I am using the "dcases" environment of the "mathtools" package with nested other environments inside it. The whole expression does not fit on a single page and so I am wondering if it is possible to spread it over more than page.

`\displaybreak` inside the "dcases" environment does not work (as its use seems to be prohibited there).

To just make 2 different "dcases" on each page is no so solution either because I do not want the bracket to close on the first page and reopen on the next. The main bracket of the "dcases" should end with a vertical line on the first page and start with an aligned vertical line on the next page.

What I like to do is

```
\begin{dcases}
  ... several cases ....
  -> Suggest page break but continue this environment on the next page <-
  .. more cases ...
\end{dcases}
```

EDIT: I tried to add pictures but it seem that my "reputation" is too low to do so - you can find the pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAc8t.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1n8c.png).
The picture shows the first page and the beginning of the second page - the gray part is the space between the two pages. The "cases" bracket should span both pages.

Comment: @Mark: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it).

Comment: Acknowledged :).

Comment: @Mark: Do you _really_ want to do this? I don't think your readers will like it. A preferable solution would be to try and break things into smaller pieces. Perhaps you can post a link to an (approximate) image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: resize the whole environment that it fits on one page.

Comment: I collect the results of a rather long calculation and I am already using A3 landscape to fit all the formulas on there. Resizing is no option because the font will become far to small to be legible.

Comment: @Mark: Still, if there's _any_ possibility to split the thing and make it two clean pages, go for it.

Comment: In such cases it is best to post a complete, compilable but minimal example. Then people which know a lot about multi-page environments but never used `dcases` before can also easily help you and post a working solution.

Comment: I think "dcases" behaves exactly as "cases". It's just that the internal symbol size is different. A minimal example would be the one I outlined above - take a "cases" environment and generate so many cases that it would need more than one page.

Comment: @Mark: As I said above, you could post a link to an (approximate) image of what you want to achieve. I could have a look and try to make suggestions.

Comment: @Hendrik: I added your requested image.

Comment: @Mark: Nope, I meant an image _with the actual content_. What you want _in principle_ was nicely described (good!) and clear.

Comment: @Hendrik: I added a second link to a screenshot of the current output. The "cases" bracket extends beyond the area of the page and is not continued on the next page.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks a lot! Now the next question: Whom are you preparing this for?

Comment: For formulas this size, I'd definitely go for making a separate display for each case. Having a giant, page spanning brace in the left margin really doesn't add any value.

Comment: @Hendrik: This will be a document for internal use of our institute.

Comment: @Harald: Of course this is a possibility. Nevertheless the "cases" style keeps it in a coherent style with the other pages.

Comment: @Mark: Ah, thanks. Then I'd follow Harald's suggestion. Moreover, there are several terms that occur repeatedly. It would probably be a good idea to give those new names; then the formulas will be shorter. To be honest, I still can't imagine that anyone will _really_ want to read this in detail, and I'm a mathematician who is used to pages and pages of formulas.

Comment: It is the closed form solution of a problem that is usually crudely proximated by numeric means. This is the 'raw' form of the result and it will be optimized and turned into code. Nevertheless, I was just wondering if this is easily possible in Tex but that does not seem the case.

Comment: @Mark: Maybe it's possible in TeX, but I thought it better to convince you _not_ doing it. And it's great to have a closed form solution, but it should be optimized _before_ typesetting, in my opinion `:-)`

Comment: Sure - but to optimize it I have to write it down as a first step. I could do it by hand but I do not trust myself to achieve this without introducing a fair amount of hardly traceable bugs :).

Comment: @Mark: Don't forget to write "@Hendrik" if you want to notify me. Correctly, it's best to first typeset it in the longish way you had, but then still I'd follow Harald's suggestion as this is probably very temporary anyway.